# How to get DataGridView Row back color to change

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView control with

```
dgridView.DataSource = QueryCustomers(LastName)    // return IList from LINQtoSql
```

I am using the following to alter Row BackColor:

```
Private Sub dgridView_OnPrePaint(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs) Handles dgridView.RowPrePaint

    Dim dgridRow As DataGridViewRow = dgridView.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    Select Case dgridRow.Cells("Status").Value
        Case "Alpha"
            dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Case "Beta"
            dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightGreen
        Case "Terminated"
            dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Salmon
        Case Else
            If currentColor = Color.White Then
                dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Silver
            Else
                dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White
            End If

            currentColor = dgridRow.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor
    End Select
End Sub
```

This seems to work except that with certain queries, the DataGridView will continue to flicker until I edit a row and save. Editing is performed by double-clicking one of the rows causing a WinForm to display over the main form containing the DataGridView. Once I save the data, and data changes in the data grid, the flickering stops.

Is there a better way to color the rows? I don't want to iterate the DataGridView everytime something changes. It seems like subscribing to the RowPrePaint event would be the thing to do. Do I need to subscribe to the RowPostPaint?

NOTE: answers can be C# or VB.Net.

Comment: Have you tried the **CellFormatting** Event of the grid

Comment: @V4Vendetta: I believe I did try CellFormatting event and I ended up with Columns colored instead of Rows...very odd.

Comment: If the data fetching is performed by the user (via a button-press) - why don't you perform the painting of the rows then ?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit too late.. but I'd rather you do the formatting after the grid has been populated with data with a loop for each of the grid's Rows.

Like so:

```
  for each dr as datagridviewrow in me.dgridrow.rows
       'condition for each row based on cell's input is put here
      if  dgridRow.Cells("Status").Value = "Alpha" then
          dr.defaultcellstyle.backcolor = color.lightgreen
      end if
   next
```

Yep... hope that help anyone in the future..